# How to remove a set of chars from a string if it exists

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have a file having below strings formats:

```
abc
xyz
statexyz_pqr_mho
dce
statelop_pqz_mho
```

I am in need to remove from all lines till **'_'** if **state** word exists in the beginning of the string

So the final list should be  -

```
abc
xyz
pqr_mho
dce
pqz_mho
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
sed '/^state/s/^[^_]*_//' foo.txt
```

**Explanation**

We first match state at the beginning of the line with `/^state/`.

Then we delete everything up to and including the first underscore by using the non-greedy matching `^[^_]*`

On input:

```
abc
xyz
statexyz_pqr_mho
dce
statelop_pqz_mho
```

This will output

```
abc
xyz
pqr_mho
dce
pqz_mho
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - it worked perfectly and many thanks for the explanation

Comment: `sed 's/^state[^_]*_/_/'` is 2 characters shorter ;)